# How to write a small ruby web server?

Tags: ruby, webserver

I have a ruby script that also needs to serve a few static files in a directory (such as an index.html, CSS and JS directories). What is the best way to write a little inline web server to serve these files?

### Solution:

```
require 'webrick'
web_server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3000, :DocumentRoot => Dir.pwd + '/web')
trap 'INT' { web_server.shutdown }
web_server.start
```

Or add this to your `.bash_profile` for an easy way to serve up the files in any directory:

```
alias serve="ruby -rwebrick -e\"s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3000, :DocumentRoot => Dir.pwd); trap('INT') { s.shutdown }; s.start\""
```

Comment: What's wrong with [WEBrick](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/index.html)?

Comment: for 1.9.3 `trap('INT')` otherwise getting syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sarnold mentioned that thin is a good server, rack will use thin with a very high priority. And bellow is a one line way to go if you have the rack gem installed:

`rackup -b "use Rack::Static, :index => 'index.html'; run Rack::File.new('.')"`

If there's no 'index.html' in the current directory, the directory contents will be listed.

Comment: Nice! I like that even better.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the simplest ruby HTTP server you can find:

```
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 5000
```

It will serve content from the running directory on port 5000.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something pure-Ruby and simple, [WEBrick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEBrick) is a good choice. Because it is pure-Ruby, it won't go very fast.

[Mongrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongrel_%28web_server%29) is partially implemented in C and Ruby and is better for performance than WEBrick. (The Ruby on Rails development mode will use Mongrel in preference to WEBrick if Mongrel is installed.)

If you'd like your server to scale better than either of WEBrick or Mongrel, then [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) is probably the choice -- it glues Mongrel together on top of [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) to scale further than the other, simpler, systems can scale.

Nothing will quite replace running a full-blown web server such as [`nginx`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx), but integrating that into your application is significantly more work for you and your users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)?

It might be what you're looking for.